# Best package(s) for making sticky labels?

Tags: packages, sticky-labels

I’m looking to print sheets of sticky labels.  There seem to be plenty of packages designed for this, or for sufficiently similar purposes that they can be straightforwardly used for this: [`labels`](https://ctan.org/pkg/labels), [`envlab`](https://ctan.org/pkg/envlab), [`flabels`](https://ctan.org/pkg/flabels), [`jlabels`](https://ctan.org/pkg/jlabels), [`bizcard`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bizcard), [`ticket`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ticket), and more.

From a quick look at their documentation, none of them clearly stand out from the crowd as “best”.  So in hope that someone else has compared these carefully already, I ask: **What are the best packages for producing sticky labels, and (if several are worth recommending) how do their features compare?**

In case “best” is too vague or subjective, the kinds of criteria I’m looking for are:

- robust, not buggy!
- generally well-designed, following good package design principles
- easy to specify layout of labels on page stock (e.g. `labels` has various standard stock formats pre-defined, plus a fairly clear interface for customising further)
- minimal restrictions/interference in typesetting the content of labels (e.g. with `labels`, it seems quite difficult to [get centered text on labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232116/centered-text-in-sticky-labels-package), which is a bit annoying)

Comment: Note: This is close to a duplicate of [Is there a good document template for making business cards?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4693/is-there-a-good-document-template-for-making-business-cards) — the tasks aren’t the same, but they’re close, and the accepted answer there is a good answer for this.  So quite possibly this should be closed as a duplicate.  (However, I think there’s value to having this specific question at least asked separately, since my first few searches on keywords like “labels”, “sticky labels” etc didn’t succeed in finding that question.)

Answer (score 1):

I use the `envlab` package. An example is in *TUGboat* 27,2 2006 in the *Glisterings* article http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-2/tb87glister.pdf